# where condition for json_encode value stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, search, where-clause, codeigniter-3

My value stored in the database looks like this `["7","8"]` and i want to check if my search value is present in it for that i had used my code like this

```
       $this->db->where_in(json_decode('tool_id'),$tool_id);
       $this->db->where('status',0);
       $query=$this->db->get('tbl_tools_supplied');
       return $query->result();
```

my all values are stored like this in `tool_id` column here its not getting the output so is there any other way

Comment: you cant do like this

Comment: @SureshKamrushi can you please tell me how can i do this

Comment: You need to use MySQL's built-in JSON functions, not PHP functions.

Comment: it tries to search like `$this->db->where_in("tool_id", $tool_id);` you can try like `$this->db->where_in("tool_id", '%"'.$tool_id.'"%');`

Comment: @Barmar i had used like this `$this->db->where(JSON_CONTAINS('tool_id',$tool_id));` but it shows error like this `Call to undefined function JSON_CONTAINS() `

Comment: You're trying to call a PHP function named `JSON_CONTAINS()`. You need to use a raw query if CodeIgniter doesn't have methods that translate to it.

Comment: To use inbuilt Mysql Json function you need column datatype should be JSON

Comment: @SureshKamrushi i don't have a datatype JSON in my mysql

Comment: Try `$this->db->where("JSON_CONTAINS('tool_id',$tool_id)", 1);`

Comment: @Nick getting error like `FUNCTION abc.JSON_CONTAINS does not exis`

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: mysql version is 5.6.17

Comment: Ah, then you don't have native JSON functions in your version :(

Comment: @Nick can we use other functions than JSON

Comment: You could try this: `$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET($tool_id, replace(replace(replace(tool_id, '[', ''), ']', ''), '\"', ''))");`

Comment: @Nick that's great...it works

Comment: i can put tick if you paste it as an answer any way thanks a lot

Comment: how can we use same condition if `$tool_id` contains multiple values

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET("7", REPLACE(REPLACE(tool_id,'[', ''), 
                      ']',''))

Answer (score 0):

you can not search your id in where condition of sql query if column store data as json,but you can fetch all records and then filter out result array of mysql query by match your id.